# Using Create Fishnet in ArcMap to create polygon based on point data

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap

I'm trying to create a polygon based on point data (crime data from Police UK). I am using the `Create Fishnet` tool. However I don't know what to fill in Output Feature Class and Template Extent.

Comment: You may be using the wrong tool, since `Create Fishnet` doesn't work "based on point data".  The `Create Thiessen Polygons` tool (which requires an Advanced license)  *does* create polygons based on point distribution.  Depending on what you're trying to model, a hexagon tessellation might be a better way to partition space than the rectangles of `CreateFishnet_management`

Comment: Also `point density` in combination with raster calculator may be helpful.

Answer (score 1):

`out_feature_class` is a mandatory parameter which includes the path to and name of your output vector file. Esri supports shapefiles (`.shp`) as a vector format. Feature classes can also be vector formats within a file geodatabase (`.gdb`), or within a Personal Geodatabase (`.mdb`). Output Feature Class is your output fishnet.

The  `template` extent is a non-mandatory parameter that includes the spatial extent of your output fishnet. (min-x, max-x, min-y, max-y coords). The tool can work without it, and has some default extent, probably inherited from the input file, i.e. your point vector.

Please refer to ArcGIS help on [How Create Fishnet Works](http://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/tool-reference/data-management/how-create-fishnet-works.htm) for more info on the tool and on spatial extents, and to the help on [Create Fishnet](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/tools/data-management-toolbox/create-fishnet.htm) for details about all tool's parameters.